# Running a Grunt task before MVN in a Build pipeline?

Tags: maven, gruntjs, ibm-cloud, devops

This question is very specific to Bluemix DevOps.

I have a Java backend application that has a sizeable JavaScript front-end. So I created a GRUNT task to do the needed: uglify, minify, CDNify etc. My current setup is to have the Bluemix build just running `mvn -B package` and the Grunt task beforehand as a script on my local machine:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    grunt build
    git add --all
    git commit
    git push origin master
```

But that precludes any edit using the online editor. So I'd like to have both task to run by the pipeline. I see 3 options:

1. Run both tasks in one build block triggered by `git push` as separate tasks
2. Run them in one build script triggered by `git push`
3. Run 2 pipeline steps, the first triggered by `git push`, the second by the completion of the first
4. something else

I haven't tried it yet (shame on me), just wanted to ask if someone did that before (If yes - cool, if no I will post my findings later on)

Comment: [This page at Bluemix](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/deployingapps.html) mentions that if a `Gruntfile` is present in your app root, it will be run before deployment - does that work on your app?

Comment: My challenge here is: I already have a pom.xml - so the cf push would pick only one. Also that explanation works for cf push, but not the build pipeline. Mixing languages is a mess (I like mess). But thx for chipping in

Comment: Ah I see. Well, if you like mess :) the next step might be a custom buildpack that has grunt and maven in it, and triggers a build each time you do 'git push', that way you can still use the online IDE. I've done similar stuff on Heroku with PHP apps that needed Grunt tasks run during the build.

Comment: Just solved it... 2 build steps were needed

Answer (score 4):

Solved it. This is what I tried:

- <strike>modify the script in build and prefix with npm install</strike>
   npm or mvn (depends on what I selected) wasn't found)
- <strike>add 2 jobs to one build stage, one grunt one maven</strike>
   (the deploy task would not find the war file)
- Use 2 pipeline stages (see picture below) : Horray --- that worked.

[image: Two build steps required]

None of the build steps required setting a directory, which is a little trap, since `mvn` sets `target` as default directory, so remove this. The script for Bower/Grunt is this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 npm install
 grunt build
```

the script for the maven task:

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn -B package
```

works like a charm (just be careful not to add npm modules you don't actually need, it slows the build quite a bit)